# Resource management like std::unique_ptr, but for identifiers rather than pointers

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

When wrapping C-like APIs that use pointers on undefined structures, I generally go to `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter to handle resources.

Occasionally, the C API will attribute integer IDs rather than pointers to the resources. I was wondering what would be the best practice to handle those. Should I rewrite a class similar to `std::unique_ptr` just for the sake of handling IDs than pointers? Should I dynamically allocate memory for those IDs to get a pointer I can pass to `std::unique_ptr`? Should I reinterpret the ID as a pointer? Or is there (hopefully) a better solution yet?

Comment: The laziest option is to simply reinterpret/convert the integer into a pointer and in the custom deleter you provide to the `unique_ptr` just reinterpret it back to the integer and call approptiate deleter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you could (ab)use std::unique_ptr for this, it seems clearer and very simple to write your own template class.  You can decide whether the deleter is part of the type (as in unique_ptr) or a constructor argument (as in shared_ptr).  You may also want some bespoke classes where there are meaningful operations to be performed directly on the handle (copying, indexing into it, etc).